# how create filter to show only one of blended chart ? DataStudio

Tags: looker-studio

I have Blended data source from 3 datasources : 3 tables,
I have 3 timeseries charts in one Chart.
Is there any option how to show only selected charts ? like Some Interactive Control filter chart option.
[image]

Hi Nim, any idea why this is not working in my chart ?
here is the report link https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/7ff6cf1b-7478-4cb1-88b2-83246fc83234/page/WadOB

and here is the screenshots, I did the same as you in video, I would like to have by default all 3 charts, and optionally to switch off any chart,
when I click on new button in view mode > nothing happened

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way it can be achieved is by incorporating [Optional Metrics](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9484925).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/107e4f5d-e87b-4409-b1bc-f2dc7fb09207) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]

[Source of Stats](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases)